# What are these connectors for?

Tags: motherboard, desktop-computer, connector

I am probably too young to recognize these connectors, since I've only seen them on older mainboards. Can anybody tell me what they are called and what they are/were used for, maybe even protocols and other good to know specs?:

These white ones next to the RAM modules

[image]

and
these large black ones
[image]

Thank you! :)

Comment: As much as it pains me to say this (as someone contemporary to this tech) - If you do get further into messing with this system, there's a retrocomputing site on this network that might be of use. ISA wasn't THAT long ago was it? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Top photo SIMM sockets (single inline memory module)

Bottom photo 16 bit ISA expansion slots (industry standard architecture)

Comment: So SIMM is basically the predecessor or DIMM and ISA somewhat another earlier form of PCI?

Comment: yes. they had similar functions.

Comment: I'd guess if this had SIMMs AND DIMMs, the system might have been contemporary to the transition between the two, and might have let you use one or the other

Comment: the various date stamps on the parts 1996  to 1999 suggest that that was the case,